# Pyramid TranslationString not working on json renderer

Tags: python, pyramid

In a test I am doing in a pyramid application, I am trying to send a translatable text via JSON, but the translation is not working. At the beginning of the file I am importing the translation string function:

```
from pyramid.i18n import TranslationString as _
```

Then consider the following code:

```
@view_config(route_name='transtest', renderer='json')
def transtest_view(request):
    return { 'myvar': _('temp-test', default='Temporary test', domain='myapp') }
```

But what I get is:

```
{"myvar": "temp-test"}
```

Note that if I change the renderer to a test template I did as follows:

```
@view_config(route_name='transtest', renderer='../templates/transtest.pt')
...
```

then the text gets translated correctly (note that I already initialized the catalogs, updated them, compiled them, etc.)

This made me think that the TranslationString class does not work right in a 'json' renderer? If so, how can I make to send a translatable string via JSON?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why did you wrap that in a `_()` did you mean to store the value as a tuple??

Comment: I was following the example at pyramid i18n documentation and I saw that in this case it returns a tuple. How can I do to get just the translated string?

Comment: As a FWIW I'd suggest using the `TranslationStringFactory` to avoid repeating the domain everywhere: `from translationstring import TranslationStringFactory`, then `_ = TranslationStringFactory(domain='myapp')`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried using the TranslationStringFactory but in a json renderer I am still not getting the translated string. If I use a normal .pt renderer I do get the translated string. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Stephan: No, `_(...)` is a convention for creating translatable messages that internationalisation tools can pick up on.

Comment: @RolandPish: that's because the template explicitly translates messages. You'll need to do the same here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly translate your message string, using [`get_localizer()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/i18n.html#pyramid.i18n.get_localizer) and [`Localizer.translate()`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/i18n.html#pyramid.i18n.Localizer.translate):

```
from pyramid.i18n import get_localizer

@view_config(route_name='transtest', renderer='json')
def transtest_view(request):
    message = _('temp-test', default='Temporary test', domain='myapp')
    return {'myvar': get_localizer(request).translate(message)}
```

Normally, templates take care of these steps for you, but for JSON you'll need to do so yourself.

You probably want to define a [`TranslationStringFactory`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/i18n.html#pyramid.i18n.TranslationStringFactory) for your project, and reuse that to produce your message strings. Add the following to your project:

```
from pyramid.i18n import TranslationStringFactory

myapp_domain = TranslationStringFactory(domain='myapp')
```

then use:

```
from my.project import myapp_domain as _

# ....

message = _('temp-test', default='Temporary test')
```